# Display CPU usage separately (without root privileges)

Tags: linux, unix, cpu-usage

I need to display the CPU usage for each processing core on a single shared-memory 12-core (SMP) machine.  I don't have access to install htop, else I would simply use that.  I don't need fancy graphs or meters, though they would be nice.

For example, simply displaying:

```
X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
```

where each X is the percentage utilization of 1 of the 12 processing cores on my machine.

*FYI: I know I can simply look at the utilization in "top" and divide that number by the number of cores on my machine, but I prefer a solution that shows each core separately.*

Answer (score 0):

```
  grep ^cpu /proc/stat
```

The columns are

- user: normal processes executing in user mode
- nice: niced processes executing in user mode
- system: processes executing in kernel mode
- idle: twiddling thumbs
- iowait: waiting for I/O to complete
- irq: servicing interrupts
- softirq: servicing softirqs

Time units are in USER_HZ or Jiffies (typically hundredths of a second).

So you can do

```
  grep ^cpu[0-9] /proc/stat | cut -d' ' -f1,5
```

Or maybe use awk to convert these numbers into percentages and display them the way you want.

References:
[Linux Howtos](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm)

Comment: This is great... but how can I compute utilization percentage given those values?